# Serializing a TreeItem (workarounds accepted)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm using a JavaFX8 TreeView. It works with TreeItem objects and everything has been straightforward so far.

Now I need to take the root TreeItem and serialize it because I need to write it and its children to a file, but TreeItem is not Serializable.

I looked for workarounds like representing it in JSON using gson library but maybe it's too complex or there are circular links inside causing a stack overflow error.

I tried to extend TreeItem class but it doesn't work well with getValue() and the related objects I associate to the TreeItem itself, even if I'm 100% sure the value objects are Serializable.

Maybe I should represent the TreeItem and its children with a similar Tree data structure but I'm a kind of lost right now.

What would you suggest?

Comment: It'd be better to persist the actual model; granted, the `TreeItem` class seems like a model class but it's more like a view-model. However, you could always subclass `TreeItem` and implement [`Externalizable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Externalizable.html). You'd write the value, then the number of children, then each child; make sure you only ever use the subclass as child `TreeItem`s. You won't be able to save the graphic, if present, this way. If you'd prefer using JSON or XML, but it isn't working, then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This looks like a good way to go. I'll try later. Thank you.